# Commensurator of a subgroup of matrices

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, arithmetic-groups

Let $k$ be a totally real number field and let $\mathcal{O}_k$ denote its ring of integers. If $H$ is a subgroup of $\text{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ let denote with $H(k)$ and $H(\mathcal{O}_k)$ the intersections $H\cap \text{GL}(n, k)$ and  $H\cap \text{GL}(n, \mathcal{O}_k)$.

Let $H$ be a semisimple algebraic group defined over $k$.
I need to show that $H(k)$ commensurates $H(\mathcal{O}_k)$, i.e. that for every $\gamma\in H(k)$ the subgroup $\gamma H(\mathcal{O}_k)\gamma^{-1}$ is commensurable to $H(\mathcal{O}_k)$.

I do not have any idea of how to proceed. The only observation I have done is that since the commensurator of a subgroup is group, and the constant matrices commensurate $H(\mathcal{O}_k)$, I can suppose that $\gamma$ has entries in $\mathcal{O}_k$, but in this way I probably lose the information of $\gamma$ being an element of $H$.

Comment: Also posted in [math.stackexchange]( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3365855/commensurator-of-a-subgroup-of-matrices)

Comment: Please do not post the same question to both sites at the same time. Pick one site (the one you think it most appropriate), polst, and wait for a response.  Wait longer than 40 minutes on a weekend. **If** you fail to secure responses in one site and you think you might get them in the other, then indicate in your post that it is a cross-post, to avoid possible duplication of effort.

Comment: I deleted the one in stack exchange, sorry :)

Comment: For the question to make sense, you need to fix an embedding of $k$ into $\mathbf{R}$. Also, are you assuming that $H$ is a $k$-subgroup? Otherwise I'm surprised by the generality.

Comment: Yes, of course $k$ is equipped with a fixed embedding in $\mathbb{R}$. With $k$-subgroup do you mean that $H$ is contained in $\text{GL}(n, k)$? Because in such case I think that since we are  in any case working with the $k$-points of $H$ there should be no difference. $H$ is semisimple, but I do not know if this matters: this problem comes from the proof of Proposition 2.1 of this article https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10561v6

Comment: No, I mean that $H$ is defined by algebraic equations with coefficients in $k$. In your generality, $H$ could be a dense subgroup, far from a Zariski-closed one. "*$H$ is semisimple*": this doesn't make sense for an arbitrary subgroup, but for an algebraic subgroup, or a closed one.

Comment: $H$ is algebraic, sorry for not being precise, but I did not know whether this fact could be true in general. More precisely, $H$ is the orthogonal group of a quadratic form $g$ of signature $(n,1)$ defined over $k$. The context is the one of arithmetic groups, so one also suppose that the forms $^{\sigma_i}g$ are definite, where $\sigma_i$ are the other embeddings of $k$ in $\mathbb{R}$. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is well-known, and you don't need semisimplicity for this to hold. You can prove it by considering congruence subgroups of $H(\mathcal O_k)$ as follows. Let $\mathfrak n$ be an ideal of $\mathcal O_k$, assume that $H$ is embedded in $\mathrm{GL}_d$, so we have a well-defined reduction modulo $\mathfrak n$ from $H(\mathcal O_k)$ to $\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathcal O_k/\mathfrak n)$ and define : 
$$
\Gamma(\mathfrak n) = \{ g \in H(\mathcal O_k), g = \mathrm{Id} \pmod {\mathfrak n}\}. 
$$
This is a finite-index subgroup of $H(\mathcal O_k)$. Then if $\gamma = (a_{ij}) \in H(k)$, and we write $\gamma^{-1} = a^{ij}$ there exists $\mathfrak n$ such that $a_{ij}\mathfrak n, a^{ij}\mathfrak n \subset \mathcal O_k$ for all $i, j$ and it follows that $\gamma \Gamma(\mathfrak n^2)\gamma^{-1} \subset H(\mathcal O_k)$. In particular $H(\mathcal O_k) \cap \gamma H(\mathcal O_k) \gamma^{-1}$ contains $\Gamma(\mathfrak n^2)$ and so has finite index in $H(\mathcal O_k)$.